# Does static_cast<T>(funcReturningT()) inhibit RVO?

Tags: c++, static-cast, copy-elision

C++17 guarantees copy elision for:

```
T funcReturningT() {
  return T(...);
}

T t=funcReturningT();
```

Now if I wrap the return into a static_cast to the same type, like so:

```
T t=static_cast<T>(funcReturningT());
```

does the standard still guarantee copy elision or not?

Comment: It boils down to what static_cast<T>(T) does.  I'd hope that it will be elided as well. Someone may be able to quote a section in the standard.

Comment: The initialization expression is _prvalue_ in both cases, so nothing should change.

Answer (score 2):

**RVO is dead. Long live RVO.**

In modern C++, there are two cases corresponding to what used to be called RVO:

1. There's *NRVO*, in which the compiler is allowed to elide a local variable if it can see that that variable will just be returned eventually. If the compiler declines to elide the local variable, then it is obligated to treat it as an rvalue when it is returned, assuming certain conditions are met (thus converting a copy into a move). This is not what your question is asking about.
2. There's also *guaranteed copy elision* --- but to even use that name for it is to think about C++17 using a pre-C++17 mindset. What really changed in C++17 is that prvalues are no longer "objects without identity" but rather "recipes for creating objects". This is the reason why copy-elision-like behaviour is guaranteed.

So let's look at your statement:

```
T t=static_cast<T>(funcReturningT());
```

The expression `funcReturningT()` is a prvalue. In C++14, this would mean that immediately upon evaluating it, the implementation would have to instantiate a temporary `T` object (lacking identity), but *non-guaranteed* copy elision would allow the compiler (at its discretion) to elide such object. In C++17, it is *ready to create a `T` object* but doesn't do so immediately.

Then the `static_cast` is evaluated, and the result of it is also a prvalue of the same type. Because of this, no move constructor is required and no temporary object needs to be created. The result of the cast is just the original "recipe".

And finally, when `t` is initialized from the result of the `static_cast`, the move constructor is once again not required. The "recipe" that `static_cast` used is simply executed with `t` as the object that it creates.

The beauty of it is that *there is nothing to elide*, which is why "guaranteed copy elision" is a misnomer.

(Sometimes, temporary objects *do* need to be created: in particular, if any constructor or conversion function needs to be called at any point, then the prvalue has to be "materialized" in order for that call to actually have an object to work with. In your example, this is not necessary.)

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), `static_cast` is effectively equivalent with creating an imaginary temporary variable and using it at that place (as a _prvalue_ expression in OP's case). Doesn't that mean that `T t=static_cast<T>(funcReturningT());` is more like `T t=T(funcReturningT());` than `T t=funcReturningT();`? (Sure, effects are the same in both cases since C++17.)

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, exactly. It is the same as `T t = T(funcReturningT());`, which in C++17 is the same as `T t = funcReturningT();`.